# How to use "Custom" SLDS icon in lightning:icon tag?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds

I have a page header component that I have built using the SLDS styling, but I since SVG tags aren't allowed in lightning components, I can't use the my custom icon (my custom object uses the *airplane* tab icon).

I have tried
`<lightning:icon name="custom:custom20" />`, but it just leaves me with a square that has the color of the icon, but not the shape.

[image: Image of icon not rendering as expected.]

Is this behavior supposed to be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `iconName`, not `name`. Also, make sure you're either in SLDS (e.g. LEX) or using SLDS (e.g. `<apex:application extends="force:slds">`). Here's a working example:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <lightning:icon iconName="custom:custom20" />
</aura:application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify `iconName` instead of `name`

```
<lightning:icon iconName="custom:custom20" />
```

[**iconName :**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:icon/specification) The Lightning Design System name of the icon. Names are written in the format `utility:down` where `utility` is the category, and `down` is the specific icon to be displayed.